cout не определен
Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты
Занимаюсь изучением С++, пытаюсь решать задачи, попался на глаза пример кода, по условиям задачи нужно "Суммировать все числа заданного массива (cq. list), за исключением самого высокого и самого низкого элемента (по значению, а не по индексу!)".
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int sum(vector<int> numbers)
{
    if (numbers.size() < 2) return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int low = numbers[0], high = numbers[0];
    for (int n : numbers) {
        if (n < low) low = n;
        else if (n > high) high = n;
        sum += n;
    }
    return sum - high - low;
}

Для того чтобы понять его алгоритм, пытаюсь запустить его у себя в Visual Studiо, используя main как точку входа в программу, но скомпилировать не могу из за ошибки в строке cout функции main, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int sum(vector<int> numbers)
{
    if (numbers.size() < 2) return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int low = numbers[0], high = numbers[0];
    for (int n : numbers) {
        if (n < low) low = n;
        else if (n > high) high = n;
        sum += n;
    }
    return sum - high - low;
}

int main() {
    int numbers[]{ 6, 2, 1, 8, 10 };
    cout << sum(); // здесь пишет что cout не определен и слишком мало аргументов в функции
}


Не подключен заголовочный файл iostream. И в функцию sum вы еще почему-то ничего не передаете.

Разве функции sum не требуется задать аргумент? Как sum узнает, какой вектор обрабатывать? Вызовите sum(numbers).

Даже интересно, в последнее время на подобные вопросы прилетают голоса "за", это боты прожимают? Или действительно на сайте есть участники, приходящие в восторг от вопросов, вызванных опечатками?

Здравствуйте спасибо что откликнулись, не пойму как написать, так cout << sum(numbers); тоже подчеркивает

Разумеется подчеркивает, ведь функция принимает вектор, а numbers - это простой массив.

Понял! Спасибо
user207200     vector numbers { 6, 2, 1, 8, 10 };
cout << sum(numbers);
